# Laravel при php artisan migrate ошибка Connection refused. Решено

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Создал проект

```
laravel new blog
```

Запустил сервер

```
php artisan serve
```

По адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000/ открывается сайт Laravel.
При попытке миграции

```
php artisan migrate
```

выводится ошибка

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)

  at /home/morilon/php_proj/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
      /home/morilon/php_proj/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=blog", "root", "", [])
      /home/morilon/php_proj/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Соответственно не могу понять почему Connection refused?
Через sudo mysql -u root -p могу зайти в mysql.

Мой database.php

return [

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],


'migrations' => 'migrations',

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

];

Comment: А доступы к БД указали? Или ларка их сама придумать должна?

Comment: Настройки работы с БД хранятся в файле config/database.php содержимое файла добавил в вопрос, но там вроде все указано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня не был указан пароль для пользователя MySQL. Если кроме меня есть еще такие "умные" - укажите в файлах config/database.php и .env в полях database , username  и password одинаковые значения.

Answer (score 2):

В файле .env поменяйте строку DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 на DB_HOST=localhost. Не забудте сбросить кэш конфига php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

во первых в вашем файле config/database.php настройки по умолчанию а не ваши во вторых настройки в файле .env имеют приоритет настройки из конфига применятся только если их нет в файле .env